# Bootstrap Tabs in .NET with persist state after page refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using native bootstrap tabs and trying to persist state of the current tab after the page refresh. Here is my form bootstrap 3 with Tabs:

```
<form runat="server" id="mainForm">


<div class="Tabs">


    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li runat="server" id="liSectionContractPayments" onclick="return makeActiveTab('sectionA');">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">
                Heading 1
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="liSectionTracking" onclick="return makeActiveTab('sectionB');">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">
                Heading 2
        </li>
        <li runat="server" id="liSectionNotes>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionC" onclick="return makeActiveTab('sectionC');">
                Heading 3</li>
        </ul>


        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionContractPayments" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h4>Heading 1</h4>
                Content for heading 1  
            </div>
            <div id="sectionTracking" class="tab-pane fade">                             
                <h4>Heading 2</h4>
                Content for heading 2     
            </div>
            <div id="sectionNotes" class="tab-pane fade">                             
                <h4>Heading 3</h4>     
                Content for heading 3
            </div>


        </div>    
    </div>


    <%-- This is to keep the state of current tab. --%>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="SetActiveNavTab" runat="server" />


</form>
```

I am using a hidden field SetActiveNavTab to persist state of the current tab, to do that I have the following script:

```
<script>

/* Not working ... */
function activaTab2(tab) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
function makeActiveTab(activeTabName) {
    $('#<%=SetActiveNavTab.ClientID%>').val(activeTabName);
    activaTab2($('#<%=SetActiveNavTab.ClientID%>').val(activeTabName));
    alert(activeTabName + "AND" + activaTab2($('#<%=SetActiveNavTab.ClientID%>').val()););
}
/* Not working ... */


$(document).ready(function() {


    function activaTab(tab) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
    };

    activaTab($('#<%=SetActiveNavTab.ClientID%>').val()); 


});
</script>
```

The part which is not working is marked with comments. I can't seems to save the clicked on tab to a SetActiveNavTab hidden field. Something wrong with the script?

Also not sure if there is a better way to do that?

Comment: A full page refresh requests everything from the server anew - nothing on the page is saved (HTML is stateless by design, for good or bad). You can manually save the state of a page by updating something other than local variables: for example, storing your show/hide field states in a cookie, or using ajax to notify the web server of important state changes. When the page is refreshed you can use the saved information to reconstruct the page's state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the some part of page rather then full page post back. i-e **AJAX**

> AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

**HOW IT WORKS**

[image: Working]
[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

**FOR AJAX IN ASP.NET WEB FORMS**

In asp.net web forms you need to put update panel

[Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx)

[Understanding ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)